# Embedded PDFs in Web page are not displayed anymore on iOS 17.4

Tags: ios, pdf

It looks like the lastest version of iOS (17.4, as of this writing) prevents embedded PDFs, whatever the browser used. To be crystal-clear, I am not talking about PDFs opened in a new tab, but PDFs displayed within a Web page as external resources, along with other HTML content.

The `object` element is there, and it's size is correct, but it remains blank. No content is displayed at all.

The problem occurs whether or not I use a viewer (PDF.js) or the browser native capability to display PDF files. (Note that iOS 17.4 browsers should be able to display them natively, as *Navigator: pdfViewerEnabled* returns *true*.)

The relevant code snippet is as follows:

```js
const blob = new Blob(arrayBuffer, { type : "application/pdf" });
const documentUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const resource = document.createElement("object");
resource.type = "application/pdf";
resource.data = documentUrl;

// Or, with PDF.js:
// const resource = document.createElement("iframe");
// resource.src = "/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=" + documentUrl;
// resource.title = "(…)"; // for a11y

resourceWrapper.appendChild(resource);
```

Again, everything is fine on any OS or browser engine, with the exception of iOS 17.4 specifically.

Have you encountered a similar issue or do you have a clue as to why that is happening?
Thank you kindly for your input.